# Polyglossia + XeLaTeX worked before but the same code is not working now... Any idea

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia

I have been using XeLaTeX + polyglossia package for ages to write my documents in Thai.  There has not been any problem until recently.  The thing that is perplexing to me is that I used the exact same code that worked fine previously but somehow it does no longer work now...

Here is the snippet of my code

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=arabic]{thai}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}[Script=Thai, Scale=1.3]{TH Sarabun New:script=thai}

\XeTeXlinebreaklocale 'th_TH'

\newfontfamily{\sans}[Scale=1.0]{Helvetica}
\newfontfamily{\thai}[Scale=1.3]{TH Sarabun New}
\newfontfamily{\thaiit}[Scale=1.3]{TH Sarabun New Italic}
\newfontfamily{\thaibf}[Scale=1.3]{TH Sarabun New Bold}
\newfontfamily{\thaibi}[Scale=1.3]{TH Sarabun New Bold Italic}
```

As for as I know the above code should not have a problem... and it worked well before.  However, recently it produce an error...

Here is the relevant part in the log-file

```
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf
File: gloss-english.ldf polyglossia: module for english)
Package polyglossia Info: Default language is english.

(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-thai.ldf
File: gloss-thai.ldf polyglossia: module for thai)

Package fontspec Warning: Font "TH Sarabun New:script=thai" does not contain
(fontspec)                requested Script "Thai".


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'THSarabunNew:script=thai(0)' created for
(fontspec)             font 'TH Sarabun New:script=thai' with options
(fontspec)             [Script=Thai,Scale=1.3].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[1.3]"TH Sarabun
(fontspec)             New:script=thai/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[1.3]"TH Sarabun
(fontspec)             New:script=thai/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[1.3]"TH
(fontspec)             Sarabun
(fontspec)             New:script=thai/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->s* [1.3]"TH
(fontspec)             Sarabun
(fontspec)             New:script=thai/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'THSarabunNew(0)' created for font 'TH
(fontspec)             Sarabun New' with options [Scale=1.3].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[1.3]"TH Sarabun
(fontspec)             New/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[1.3]"TH Sarabun
(fontspec)             New/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[1.3]"TH
(fontspec)             Sarabun New/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[1.3]"TH
(fontspec)             Sarabun New/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 


./Misc58_ex.tex:39: LaTeX3 Error: Command '\thai' already defined!

For immediate help type H <return>.
```

It does seem to me that there is a problem with fontspec package.  There is anyway to solve or circumvent the problem?

PS. I use TeXShop 4.27 and xelatex in Macport (Mac OS X Mojave).  Everything is up-to-date as far as I know

Comment: Please change the command **\thai** used for font 'TH Sarabun New' to something else (eg. **\thsarabaun**). It is predefined in XeTeX. So there is a clash between two commands. Probably the change is relatively later to your code and hence the exactly same command which worked before is creating a problem.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  In a situation like this, the first thing I would try is to copy the document that worked before to a new name, and then try to process this copy.  If that doesn't work, then you know that the problem is probably caused by an update to your system, and not in your code.  If you still have the log for the original run, you can compare the version numbers of loaded packages, which will almost certainly isolate the cause of the failure.

Comment: Thanks for all your reply... There has recently been updates on both XeTeX and LaTeX2e so these cause the problem... changing the name of the command works.